# Android IOIO bluetooth lag problems

Tags: android, ioio

i'm using the IOIO library in android and a bluetooth dongle to get results of the IOIO hardware to the android phone wireless , but there seems to be some lag in communication between the IOIO and Android.

so i don't know whether it was a software issue regarding the code or a hardware issue regarding the bluetooth dongle.

specifically i'm using this code:

http://demos-ioio-irthermometer.blogspot.com/2013/07/ioio-and-mlx90614-ir-thermometer.html

to get data from the temperature sensor to android and i have 2 issues:

1-whether the connection was bluetooth or wired usb connection the tempreture reading doesn't update.

2-the bluetooth lagging problem i mentioned above where i sometimes have to reopen the android application many times so that the reading appears, unlike the usb connection where it appears in the first time but never updates.

Comment: tempreture reading doesn't update. ? ur coding ?

Comment: look at the link i have posted in the body of the question , i just copied & pasted the code nothing new...my code is as same as the one in the link. ur answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i cant find the **handleTemp()** there , i think u created one ,  is it like this ? .....

```
private void handleTemp (double temp)
{
    final float celsius = (float) (temp - 273.15);
    final float fahrenheit = (float) ((celsius*1.8) + 32);
      TempCelsius.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          TempCelsius.setText("Deg C: "+ celsius);
          TempFahrenheit .setText("Deg F: "+ fahrenheit);
        }
      });
 }
```

What does your log shows , some thing like  **RAW:xxxxxx**

Thanks ....

Comment: i have wrote a code similar as this one for handleTemp yes, but i will try your code.